# Ignore trailing NULL characters when converting string from char array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am using a JNI API (that i can't change) that return a fixed size char array that represent a string.

I am converting it to String with `String.valueOf(char [])`

The problem is that i can receive an array like this `{'a','b','c','\0','\0','\0'}`

Using `valueOf()` keeps the trailing NULLs and a I get a wrong string.

Is there a simple way to convert such and array to string and removing NULLs?

Comment: Those are *not* trailing zeros. Those are [NULL characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character). I corrected the title and body of your Question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String s = String.valueOf(bits).trim();
```

just trim the string it'll get rid of all *leading & *trailing white space.

Comment: Assuming you're ok with trimming leading whitespace too.

Comment: This is for this kind of trick that I was asking.
@shmosel the reviewer ;) that's ok is my case

Comment: For future readers: `String.trim()` removes all leading and trailing characters that are equal to or below the space (`<= 0x20`); that includes control characters.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you would get both an array and a `length` variable that tells how many characters are to be read from the array. If you don't have `length` variable you can find it with a loop and use [`new String(char[], int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(char[],%20int,%20int)) constructor:

```
char[] arr = {'a','b','c','\0','\0','\0'};
int len = 0;
do {
  len++;
} while (arr.length > len && arr[len] != '\0');
String s = new String(arr, 0 ,len);
System.out.println(s); // abc
```

Comment: You're assuming it can't start with a `\0`. And that there won't be any in middle.

Comment: You're also assuming there's at least one trailing `\0`.

Comment: thx but I was asking for a trick that i wasn't aware like @mavriksc. You answer stay nice for leading space

Answer (score -1):

I did it like this: Since the nulls are only at the end of the charArray, I went through the array backward and counted how many nulls it had. Then I iterated through the array using its length minus the number of nulls as the upper limit in the for next loop and built the final string without the trailing nulls.

Like this:

```
public String getStringFromBufferedCharArray(char[] cArray) {
    StringBuilder finalString = new StringBuilder();
    int count = 0;
    for (int x = cArray.length - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
        if ((int) cArray[x] == 0) count++;
        else break;
    }

    int end = cArray.length - count;

    for (int x = 0; x < end; x++) {
        finalString.append(cArray[x]);
    }
    return finalString.toString();
}
```